# Visualise OO PHP code

Tags: php, visualization

Does something exist that I can point to my PHP project and it can look at all the files (or just the ones that I specify) and generate a diagram based on the objects and function calls?
It would be a good way to verify that my design is actually being implimented :)

Background:
I'm trying to build a PHP website using OO principles and while, so far, it is working I still have a ways to go and already the complexity is getting out of control.
I mean, I understand basically what's going on but (and I don't think I'm alone here) it's really helpful to me if I can visualise the system at once and see the flow so I can optimise, remove unnecessary things and of course, build on the foundations.
I could sit down with a pen&paper and draw it (and I have done that for parts) but if there was some program that would generate an image, it would be much simplier. Plus I could do it more often.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857/c-c-source-code-visualization/29989#29989) is I think still valid for PHP, but I am not sure if it is totally what you want. I know some of the tools (e.g. Doxygen) work with PHP

Comment: nice one, I'll take a look at the various tools suggested in that thread. thanks :)

Comment: Doxygen does it! I had a problem with the calling graph not being displayed ('Error opening map file for inclusion in the docs'), but turned "SHORT_NAMES" on under Expert-Project and they are magically there :)

Answer (score 1):

[PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) will create a class tree from your source code, but just in text (well, HTML). Not a pretty graph.

Comment: but it doesn't appear to show method calls between objects..? anyway, I'm not worried about 'pretty' :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use profiling with xdebug you can get cachegrind files to open up with WinCacheGrind or similar. More info [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/). The [first nWire for PHP beta](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php) was just released. It is an interactive tool which lets you visualize practically every possible association in your code.