# Popular diagramming tools or methodologies for C

Tags: c, uml, diagram, call-graph

Coming from a java (and other OO backgrond ) i got very cosy in with my objects, natural encapsulation and polymorphism.

All this i expected, the one this i didn't expect was to miss my class diagrams!

When the going gets tough or you start to worry about over coupling it was always my first stop.
But i cant seem to find a C style equivalent (that doesn't date from the mid 90's) diagramming system or utility for C.

have i just missed some thing? is there a hidden gem out there some where?
Even just something to show function calls between files so i can get an idea of whats going on where.

In short: Does any one have a suggestion (or tool) for how to model C file sets? function calls, includes, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517589/tools-to-get-a-pictorial-function-call-graph-of-code

Comment: Beside the link @CongXu provided, you should consider that a 'class diagram' does make sense for C, since C does not know classes. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857/c-c-source-code-visualization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate C code from class diagrams with UML applications such as [IBM Rational Rhapsody](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rhapsody/info) or Eclipse-based open source [Topcased](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/topcased/info).

You can generate call graphs, calling graphs and dependency graphs from C code with [doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/doxygen/info), powered by [graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graphviz/info).

Comment: ended up using doxygen. its prefect.

Comment: @TrewTzu, then you were looking for tools to _document_ your code? As the question is written, it sounds like you want tools to _design_ the code. If my interpretation is correct, please edit the title of the question.

Comment: i was looking for some thing to display a call graph (except i didnt know it was called that), or really any kind of diagram of my existing system.

doxygen out puts some really great call graphs.
do you still feel i should edit it?