# Are there any programs that can visualize structure of C++ code?

Tags: c++, structure, code-visualization

I have source code that contains more than hundred source files and it is hard to understand what it does, how functions use each other, what is the flow of the execution....

Are there any programs that can visualize structure of C++ code in such a way that it is easy to understand it?

Comment: Redundant with http://stackoverflow.com/q/27857/1758762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best known tools is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which produces nice UML diagrams in some modes.