# How to visualize the code flow

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis

I would like to visualize the code flow for a C++ project that I need to modify. The code compiles and runs fine.

**Background:**
Actually I am modifying an MRI sequence code. The framework is being called idea (SIEMENS). It somehow combines visual studio 2008 and cygwin to call customized command line inputs. Even the strucutre of makefile is different from usual makefile that I usually use for C++ project. (Disclaimer: I do not understand much about makefile and its customization nor do I know much about use of cygwin.)

1) I have access to `dll` and `.so` files

2) Also, path to include files are somehow abbreviated.

**Abbreviated include statement:**

```
#include "MrServers/MrMeasSrv/SeqIF/csequence.h"
```

**Full include statement**

```
#include "C:/MIDEA/N4_VD13A_LATEST_20120616/n4/pkg/MrServers/MrMeasSrv/SeqIF/csequence.h"
```

3) My project does not start with `main();` but, it starts with `init()` and then it pass to `prep(), check(), run()`. Prep stage becomes particularly complicated.

4) The IDEA framework is designed in combination with cygwin for command line use only. So, I can not place break point.

```
Could someone suggest me how to visualize the code flow?
```

Comment: what is your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AB_  I would like to visualize the code flow. If somehow this visualization can be done at the functional level, it would be great.

Comment: Are you looking for a debugger?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857/c-c-source-code-visualization

Comment: @5gon12eder I am looking for something which can help me visualize the dependencies for already working code. I need to modify the code.

Comment: the best thing you can do is place breakpoint into init function and step into code from there

Comment: @AB_ The IDEA framework is designed in combination with cygwin for command line use only. So, I can not place break point.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It seems that DoUML may serve my purpose. But, it's asking for *.prj file and I can see only .dsp. .dsw files in my visual studio 2008 project.

Comment: Chcek out this related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27857/120163

Comment: @IraBaxter  It seems that DoUML may serve my purpose. But, it's asking for *.prj file and I can see only .dsp. .dsw files in my visual studio 2008 project.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to make the ".prj" file by hand.  Is that hard?