# Code Visualization and Arrow Annotations

Tags: visualization, code-visualization

I would like to generate a code visualization that displays

- full source code file
- with arrows connecting lines
- Syntax highlighting (initially PHP, but extensible)

To clarify, I have an analysis that already computes a relationship between some of the lines of code. My need is to display this.

Is there already a tool or framework that allows me to do this?

**Edit:** This is what this would look like.

[image: This is what this would look like.]

Comment: Can you produce a sketch/prototype of what you want? This could help to provide you the right type of answer.

Comment: Updated with the example.

Comment: TBH your example doesn't make much sense to me. The only relationship I may see in there is between `f()` and the `f` function. All the other arrows seem to point random stuff.

Comment: That's OK. It will make perfect sense in context. And I have an analysis to generate the edges. What I need is a way to visualize all that. In a perfect world, it would be some API `generateHTML(String code, String language, Map<Integer,Integer> edges)` where `language` is for syntax highlighting and `edges` is a map of edges (line number to line number).

Comment: Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857/c-c-source-code-visualization